# Setting up django registration for custom user (Validing user creation form for custom user causes no such table: app_appuser)

Tags: django, registration

I am trying to register my custom user on django website. My register view (that was wrote for standard user) throws `no such table: app_appuser`

model:

```
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    miniature = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile_photos', default="defaults/default.png", validators=[validate_miniature_file_extension])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

form:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.AppUser
        fields = ("username", "full_name")
```

post method that is responsible for registration:

```
def post(self, request):

        form = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'register.html', { 'form': form })
```

I tried to run `makemigrations`, and `syncdb` and it didn't help me. I also have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.AppUser'` to my settings.py file.

And my question is: how to setup registration for it?

Comment: Can you add your error traceback?

Comment: Is there a table `app_appuser` in your DB?